Is there an automated method to translate a GitHub action yaml to a GitLab .gitlab-ci.yml file?
I have a GitHub action yaml for CI/CD and I need to create a GitLab .gitlab-ci.yml file that accomplishes the same results. Is the best way to go about this to look for equivalencies for every keyword and syntax using the documentation linked to below?  Are there tools that automate any of this or are we stuck translating line by line, section by section?
Before I take on a laborious chore I thought best to check here. Thank you!
Best documentation I could find:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/migration/github_actions.html
